Why is Kateryna Lagno's federation given as RUS while other Russian players' federations are given as FID?

In the June 2024 rating list, Lagno's federation is given as RUS, while Goryachkina, Shuvalova and Garifullina's federations are all FID. Why don't they all have the same federations?
Edit: Still the case as of November 2024.

same with the mens as well
